# Psql - How to skip row when error in address during Geocoding

Tags: psql

Am Geocoding hundreds of thousands of records, while this query is running if the address does not produce a Lat and Long value for a particular row it shows an error "invalid input syntax for integer: "J199" ". So if this line

*(geocode_intersection(crashroad,crashreferenceroad,state,city,'',1)*

Produces a value like "J199",it has to skip that row. So how to do this?

```
update nj.condition_3 
set (rating,new_address,points) = ( COALESCE((g.geo).rating,-1),pprint_addy((g.geo).addy),st_astext(ST_SnapToGrid((g.geo).geomout, 0.000001)))
-- Replace in limit value if error occurs
FROM (SELECT addid FROM nj.condition_3 WHERE rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) As a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT addid, (geocode_intersection(crashroad,crashreferenceroad,state,city,'',1)) As geo  
-- Replace in limit value if error occurs
FROM nj.condition_3 As ag WHERE ag.rating IS NULL ORDER BY addid LIMIT 3) As g ON a.addid = g.addid
WHERE a.addid = nj.condition_3.addid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function to overcome this Error. So now it is working fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION geocode_all_values() RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
r record;
g record;
BEGIN
 FOR r IN select * from TableName where rating is null order by Sno
LOOP
BEGIN
FOR g IN select * from geocode_intersection(r.Street1,r.Street2,r.state,r.city,'',1)
LOOP
  update TableName
  set new_address = pprint_addy(g.addy),
  rating = g.rating,
  points = ST_AsTEXT(g.geomout)
  where sno = r.sno;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```